# How can I check the permissions of a specific group?

Tags: permissions

I've a group on my system and I don't know which permission it has. Where can I find all group permissions?

I want to have an output like this:

```
folders owned by group 'test'

/home/test/Documents/    
/home/test/Pictures/    
/var/www/website/    
var/www/python/
```

Answer (score 49):

You can see the rights of group by `ls -l` in terminal to see the permissions of corresponding files.

```
drwxrwxr-x   3 owner group    4096 Jun 23 17:15 Calibre Library
-rw-rw-r--.  1 owner group   44444 May 25 11:36 custom 1.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x.  4 owner group    4096 Jul 11 21:26 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x.  2 owner group    4096 Jul  9 20:35 Documents
drwxr-xr-x. 13 owner group   12288 Jul 11 12:42 Downloads
drwx------.  7 owner group    4096 Jun 23 13:21 Dropbox
```

Which can be further shown

[image]

You can refer to [File Permissions](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html) for changing permissions. Whereas following commands are used to change it.

```
chmod - modify file access rights
su - temporarily become the superuser
chown - change file ownership
chgrp - change a file's group owner
```

---

**EDIT :** To view the files owned by the group "**test**" and user "**luser**'  use [FIND command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html)

to find all the groups available on your system:

```
cat /etc/group |cut -d: -f1
```

eg. for finding the groups that the current user belongs to

```
groups
luser test adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

then looking for groups **luser** belongs to

```
groups luser
luser : test luser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Now to see the files owned by group "**test**" in particular path or folder. Try

**`find /home -group test`**

**`find /etc -group root`**

---

**GUI method via Nautilus** , select the **`Group, Permissions , Owner`** options from the Nautilus Preferences menu.

[image]

Then in Nautilus File manager , by selecting **Icons views** you will get the group name under icon as

[image]

And in **list view** you will get something like

[image]

Comment: Thats not an answer on my question. See my edited post.

Answer (score 7):

Groups don't have permissions so to say...

Each file/folder is owned by a user and a group. If your group owns the file/folder then you'll have the permissions in the second group of permissions.

For example, let's say a file has:

```
-rwxrw-r--
```

Split this into thirds, excluding the first character (this is a special character):

- `rwx` (Owner) - The owner has read/write and execute permissions.
- `rw-` (Group) - The group has read and write permissions.
- `r--` (Everyone else) - Everyone else has read permissions.

You can change these permissions using chmod and you can change who owns them by using chown. To learn more about these commands, open a terminal and type `man chmod` or `man chown`.

Comment: But how can I see which folders/files got owned by a certain group?

Comment: @ OrangeTux cd to directory and enter ls -al That will give a complete readout of permissions.

Comment: Thats not an answer on my question. See my edited post.

Answer (score 4):

You would type in the following command:

```
find / -group test 2>/dev/null
```

Syntax description:

```
find       = Find command
/          = from root Directory down
-group     = search for a group where ...
test       = ...group name equals 'test'
2          = Error Output ...
>          = ...is redirected...
/dev/null  = ...to device NULL (no Output)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
find / -group name_of_group
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the permissions of all files and folders associated with the group `test` in the mentioned folders you can use

```
find /home/test/Documents /home/test/Pictures /var/www/website var/www/python -group test -printf %M -print
```

- `-printf %M` will output the permissions in the same form `ls-l` does, not followed by a newline
- `-print` adds the filename followed by a newline.

Reference: `man find`.

To see the permissions of the mentioned folders you can use

```
ls -ld /home/test/Documents /home/test/Pictures /var/www/website var/www/python
```